# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won't work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying like hours to make a simple MySQL command and it won't work.
I have a database where package IDs for Apps are stored, like 'com.android.package'.
They are stored like so:

```
| ID | PackageID           | PackageDesc       |
| 1  | com.android.package | This is a package |
| 2  | com.android.test2pa | This is package 2 |

And so on...
```

Now I want to insert a new entry, if 'com.android.package' don't exist and if it exists, I want to do nothing...

I've tried following:

```
 INSERT INTO Packages (PackageID) VALUES ('com.android.package') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PackageID=VALUES(PackageID)
```

But it still creates new entries, like that:

```
| ID | PackageID           | PackageDesc       |
| 3  | com.android.package |                   |
| 4  | com.android.package |                   |
| 5  | com.android.package |                   |
```

I don't know where's my error.

Comment: For `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work, `PackageID` must be either the PK or a Unique index. Is this the case with your table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ´PackageID´ is a string (text), ´ID´ is the unique identifier.

Comment: In that case `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` won't work because there is not duplicates as far as MySQL is concerned.

Comment: How do I perform this task then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposed `Packages` table schema for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work as expected is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Packages (
   `ID` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `PackageID` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   `PackageDesc` VARCHAR (100),
   UNIQUE(`PackageID`)
);
```

After this statement is executed:

```
INSERT INTO Packages (PackageID, PackageDesc) VALUES 
('com.android.package', 'This is a package') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PackageID=VALUES(PackageID);
```

`Packages` contains the following row:

```
# ID, PackageID,            PackageDesc
'1', 'com.android.package', 'This is a package'
```

If you now execute the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO Packages (PackageID, PackageDesc) VALUES 
('com.android.package', 'This is a package2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PackageID=VALUES(PackageID), PackageDesc=VALUES(PackageDesc);
```

`Packages` contains:

```
# ID, PackageID,            PackageDesc
'1', 'com.android.package', 'This is a package2'
```

This means an `UPDATE` was performed by the latter `INSERT INTO`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec9ad/1)

Comment: It still duplicates. When I execute  `INSERT INTO Packages (PackageID, PackageDesc) VALUES 
('com.android.package', 'This is a package2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PackageID=VALUES(PackageID), PackageDesc=VALUES(PackageDesc);` it creates a new entry containing `com.android.package' and 'This is a package2'`, but if i execute the entry again, it duplicates this entry with a new id...

Comment: @Fusseldieb Have you *altered* your table schema in order to make `PackageID` unique?

Comment: @Fusseldieb But this is the most crucial part!

Comment: About one year later, your answer got accepted by me. Sorry about this :P